# how to fetch data of type org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.ResultImpl into c:forEach in jstl

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, xampp, jstl

I am new in jstl and i try to use jstl core and sql to fetch data from database.

- when I use java code i get data of type `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl`.
- when I use `sql:query` of jstl i get `org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.ResultImpl`

and `<c:forEach>`'s items doesn't accept both of them.

Java code:

```java
ResultSet result ;
try {
    Class.forName(driver);
     Connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName, userNameDB, dbpassword);
    Statement st  = Connect.createStatement();
    result = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM questions");
   
    }catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.print(e);
}
```

jstl:

```xml
    <sql:setDataSource var="myDB" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" user="root" password="" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/exposerjstl" />
        
        <sql:query var="questions" dataSource="${myDB}" >
            SELECT * FROM questions;
        </sql:query>
        <c:forEach var="row" items="${questions}">
            <div><c:out value="${row.question}" /><br>
        </c:forEach>
```

the result is:

```
Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:611)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:490)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:326)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    examenServlet.doGet(examenServlet.java:72)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:664)
    org.apache.jsp.views.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:217)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:467)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:326)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    examenServlet.doGet(examenServlet.java:72)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.toForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:274)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.supportedTypeForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:238)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.prepare(ForEachSupport.java:155)
    javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:256)
    org.apache.jsp.views.home_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(home_jsp.java:326)
    org.apache.jsp.views.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:182)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:467)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:326)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    examenServlet.doGet(examenServlet.java:72)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.43
```

Comment: i think the error here :  javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;

Comment: @BalusC thank for the information.       So is there a solution of my problems  since i use an old version of jstl (1.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

In your JSTL version the type of the `questions` attribute is [`Result`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/sql/Result.html). You cannot iterate over it, but you can iterate over `Result#getRows()`, so just replace `${questions}` with `${questions.rows}`:

```xml
<sql:setDataSource var="myDB" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                   user="root" password="" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/exposerjstl" />
<sql:query var="questions" dataSource="${myDB}" >
    SELECT * FROM questions;
</sql:query>
<div>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${questions.rows}">
    <c:out value="${row.question}" />
    <br />
</c:forEach>
</div>
```

As remarked by BalusC, the `<sql:...>` tags are mostly for prototyping. In production you should create the collection in Java code, set it as a request attribute and call the JSP template.