# How to get a value from type org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.ResultImpl into c:out

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I am a beginner in jsp and jstl. I try to query a value from my database and display it in my jsp.
If i run my application it always displays something like this:

- **org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.ResultImpl@17ed40fd**

instead of a **number or result**.

in the jsp file:

```
<sql:setDataSource var = "groceryItems" driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
                   url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/flattered"
                   user = "flattered"  password = "******"/>

<sql:query dataSource="${groceryItems}" var="result">
                    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM grocery_item;
                </sql:query>
                    <c:out value="${result}"></c:out>
```

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66428645/11748454).

Comment: Kind of @PiotrP.Karwasz , but i only want to display one number fromt the count statement and do not want to iterate over it. But if I add .something like rows or anything else it crashes and tells me that it is not existing in type org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.ResultImpl

Comment: Since the result set has one row, iterating over it will display one number. Of course you can also use `result.rows[0].count`.

Comment: Oh now I understood. Thank you for the help @PiotrP.Karwasz.